# Simple android code, not sure what's wrong

Tags: java, android

This is a simple password app, and it's not really working, i'm not sure what most of this sentences mean. I have some knowledge in c++ but this is new to me. Can somebody correct me? I can't find a site that explains this well.

```
        public void addListenerOnButton(){

    geslo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    Gumb  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Gump);

    Gumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        String text="banana";
        if(geslo.toString()==text){
            Intent newactivity= new Intent(MyActivity.this,MainDatoteka.class);
            startActivity(newactivity);
        }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `i'm not sure what most of this sentences mean` so where have you copied it from? Btw: `geslo.toString()==text` should be `geslo.getText().toString().equals(text)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 errors : you don't compare String with ==, and you have to use getText() on the EditText component :

```
if(geslo.getText().toString().equals(text))
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code :-

```
if(geslo.getText().toString().equals(text))
```

instead of

```
if(geslo.toString()==text)
```

Comment: It should be `geslo.getText().toString()...`.

Comment: thanks for rectifying me